# Xamarin.Forms XAML GridView template formatting issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin app and just can't figure out the XML. I've done a bunch of XAML on Windows Store Apps but the differences in Xamarin just seem bizarre. I have the following code for a section on my MainPage, I can't seem to get the background grid to change size with the 5 images. The main grid and gridview.itemtemplate remain a fixed size no matter what I change. So the static images head off to the right of the grid. I will try and attach a screenshot of the result. In any event, I would like the background grid to automatically size itself to the horizontal StackLayout. This is just for testing as my final solution will be to embed another GridView based on an observable collection. Just using the static images for testing.

```html
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
            <ScrollView>
                <controls:GridView 
                    ItemSelected="{Binding SelectedRack,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Racks}"
                    MaxColumns="{Binding MaxColumns}"
                    ItemTappedCommand="{Binding OnItemTappedCommand}"
                    WidthRequest="{Binding WidthRequest}"
                    TileHeight="{Binding TileHeight}"
                    ColumnSpacing="10"
                    Padding="5"
                    RowSpacing="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <controls:GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="5,5,0,0" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding State,Converter={StaticResource SensorStateToBackgroundColorConverter}}">
                                        <Image
                                            HeightRequest="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                            WidthRequest="{Binding TargetWidth}"
                                            Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                                        <Image
                                            HeightRequest="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                            WidthRequest="{Binding TargetWidth}"
                                            Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                                        <Image 
                                            HeightRequest="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                            WidthRequest="{Binding TargetWidth}"
                                            Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                                        <Image 
                                            HeightRequest="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                            WidthRequest="{Binding TargetWidth}"
                                            Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                                        <Image
                                            HeightRequest="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                            WidthRequest="{Binding TargetWidth}"
                                            Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:GridView>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: GridView doesn't exist in Xamarin. It is probably a 3rd party control and if you found the bug you should contact whomever publishes that. Of course it is legitimate to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what your control `controls:GridView` does. But the size given by that view to its children seems to be the issue here. I replaced that control with a grid and got the same issue.

> The reason is you have set the `WidthRequest` for that control, which is not required. It will restrict the width. Remove the `WidthRequest` and replace it with `HorizontalOptions` as `StartAndExpand`. That will allow the control to take whatever size is offered by its parent. It worked fine for me.
>
> **Note: If you want your view to forcefully fill the available space, use `FillAndExpand` value for your `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions` property of your view.**

---

Please find the code below.

```
<Grid Padding="5" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <ScrollView Padding="5" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Aqua" ColumnSpacing="10" Padding="5" RowSpacing="5" 
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Grid Margin="5,5,0,0" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                        <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" Source="github.png"/>
                        <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" Source="github.png"/>
                        <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" Source="github.png"/>
                        <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" Source="github.png"/>
                        <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" Source="github.png"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Name" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

---

Below is the output I got.

[image: Output image]

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I have hardcoded the values for my convenience in the example code. You can modify the code based on your requirements for the desired result. Please accept/upvote the answer if that helps for you, so that it will help others as well. 

Happy coding... :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time on this. My actual problem is the "GridView" library i was using. What I wanted is CollectionView but as I found out just now, was not available until v4.3 of forms. I just updated and that appears to be exactly what I need, and now I have the behavior I want.

Truly appreciate your help, and willingness to look into this.